# What is the difference between 0. vs 0.0 in shaders?

Tags: shader

When reading example code for a raymarching shader, I noticed that the author uses `0.`. Later in the code, they also use `0.0`. Are these the same thing, or is there a convention that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference and no convention mandating one over the other, it's just a matter of personal preference / consistency.